# Representable morphism for algebraic spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the definition of algebraic spaces, but there is a notion of representable morphism that is a little confusing to me. Let $S$ be a scheme and let $Sch/S$ denote the category of $S$-schemes. Let $f:F\rightarrow G$ be a morphism of sheaves on $Sch/S$ (with etale topology). We say that $f$ is representable by schemes if for every $S$-scheme $T$ and a morphism $T \rightarrow G$ the fiber product $F\times_G T $ is a scheme.

What exactly are $F$ and $G$? I mean, how can we take the fiber product of a scheme with a sheaf? Also, what is would be the morphism $T \rightarrow G?$

Comment: We identify schemes with the corresponding representable sheaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $T \in Sch/S$ one obtains a sheaf $h_T = Hom(-,T)$ via the Yoneda embedding. It is common to abuse notation and write $T$ for $h_T$. So a map $T \to G$ means a map $h_T \to G$, i.e. a natural transformation, and $F\times_G T$ means $F\times_G h_T$, which is the fiber product of sheaves. (The fiber product of sheaves can be computed ``pointwise" on objects, i.e. $(F\times_G h_T) (U) = F(U)\times_{G(U)}h_T(U)$.)

Comment: So if $F\times _G T$ is a scheme, they really mean it is a sheaf of the form $h_Q$ for some scheme $Q$ right?

Comment: It seems that way, although I don't know where you are reading from. I learned this from [Toen's mastercourse](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Master+course+on+algebraic+stacks) in which one considers sheaves on the category of *affine* $S$-schemes. In this case one needs to define a general (non-affine) scheme differently.